PayPal have a no-code checkout which is simple & quick, but it asks buyers for the shipping address
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=BAAM0U-DXXXq1gV7Vz_uWYyUwd_NoJ454Wm1dqvRdWby1tQ_mbqfqKblxDrOWeZlFrfiPCTykrMU1MECJ8&components=hosted-buttons&disable-funding=venmo&currency=GBP"></script>

<div id="paypal-container-GUJRJW5XXXQGY"></div>

<script>

  paypal.HostedButtons({

    hostedButtonId: "GUJRJW5XXXQGY",

  }).render("#paypal-container-GUJRJW5XXXQGY")

</script>

would anyone here know just where I put NO_SHIPPING parameter?
I tried using the SHIPPING drop down and adjusted it to 1 and it just made a mess of things, maybe there's an instruction that goes in the script-src?

At present all "No Code" checkouts always ask for a shipping address.
You can have the shipping amount be 0, but an address will be collected as part of the checkout.
In the future there might be more customization options, but that is the way it works for now.
